# sensenet installation from package fails with error after Installing content types step

Tags: sensenet

Hello sense/net community,

I am trying to install sense/net community edition.

I followed the steps in [this guide](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_install_Sense/Net) step by step

But end with following error when I run batch: **ExportSenseNet.bat**

```
2017-02-01 19:45:27.5636    Installing content types...
2017-02-01 19:46:27.3759    ========================================
2017-02-01 19:46:27.3890    Import ends with error:
2017-02-01 19:46:27.4050    ========== Exception:
2017-02-01 19:46:27.4288    SchemaEditorCommandException: Error during schema transaction rollback.
2017-02-01 19:46:27.4839       at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Schema.SchemaEditor.RegisterSchema(SchemaEditor origSchema, SchemaEditor newSchema, SchemaWriter schemaWriter) in c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Storage\Schema\SchemaEditor.cs:line 74
at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Schema.SchemaEditor.Register() in c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Storage\Schema\SchemaEditor.cs:line 25
at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Schema.ContentTypeInstaller.ExecuteBatch() in c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\Schema\ContentTypeInstaller.cs:line 110
at SenseNet.Tools.ContentImporter.ImporterClass.InstallContentTypeDefinitionsAndAspects(String ctdPath, String aspectsPath) in c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Tools\Import\ImporterClass.cs:line 388
at SenseNet.Tools.ContentImporter.ImporterClass.Run(String schemaPath, String asmPath, String fsPath, String repositoryPath, Boolean validate, Boolean resetSecurity) in c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Tools\Import\ImporterClass.cs:line 130
at SenseNet.Tools.ContentImporter.Importer.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Tools\Import\Importer.cs:line 115
2017-02-01 19:46:27.5419    ---- Inner Exception:
2017-02-01 19:46:27.5579    InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.
2017-02-01 19:46:27.6070       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Rollback()
at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Data.SqlClient.Transaction.Rollback() in c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Storage\Data\SqlClient\Transaction.cs:line 240
at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.TransactionScope.Rollback() in c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Storage\TransactionScope.cs:line 195
at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Schema.SchemaEditor.RegisterSchema(SchemaEditor origSchema, SchemaEditor newSchema, SchemaWriter schemaWriter) in c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Storage\Schema\SchemaEditor.cs:line 64
2017-02-01 19:46:27.6255    =====================
2017-02-01 19:46:27.6425    ========================================
2017-02-01 19:46:27.6595    Import is finished with 1 errors.
2017-02-01 19:46:27.6775    Read log file: C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\WebSite\Tools\importlog_20170201-194504.txt
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this? It seems like there is a problem with the SQL connection, it tries to roll back the transaction, but that fails too. If the problem still exists, please try to check if there is anything in the database...e.g. tables, stored procedures.

Comment: I tried the following : turning windows firewall off &  installing default database instance 

the problem still exists.

Please advice

Answer (score 2):

I think the SQL Alias is missing.

The default connection string use an Alias (MySenseNetContentRepositoryDatasource) for connecting to the server. Here is a default connection string:

```
<add name="SnCrMsSql" connectionString="Data Source=MySenseNetContentRepositoryDatasource;Initial Catalog=SenseNetContentRepository;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

By default the alias is MySenseNetContentRepositoryDatasource. You need set this alias in the SQL Server Configuration Manager. 
Please check it out this documentation: http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_install_Sense/Net_from_source_package_(IIS_7.5_and_IIS_7.0) 
( Point 5 [Set up database connection]  is relevant to you).

You need to create two alias, one for 32bit based applications and one for 64bit based application.

If you have more SQL instances on your machine, you should choice the correct one. For example, I have a default SQL2012 instance, and I can reach on the local machine with .. And I have an other instance of SQL version 2016, in this case this SQL server listening on .\SQL2016 url.  If I want to use the SQL2016, I need to type .\SQL2016 to Server property of the alias.

When your created the two aliases, you can try it in the SQL Management studio. I think it's a easier way to see if it works.

What is the process, which you try run? You wrote this:

> But end with following error when I run batch: ExportSenseNet.bat

but down I see it is an import

> 2017-02-01 19:45:27.5636    Installing content types... 2017-02-01
>   19:46:27.3759    ======================================== 2017-02-01
>   19:46:27.3890    Import ends with error: 2017-02-01 19:46:27.4050
>   ========== Exception: 2017-02-01 19:46:27.4288    SchemaEditorCommandException: Error during schema transaction
>   rollback. 2017-02-01 19:46:27.4839       at
>   SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Schema.SchemaEditor.RegisterSchema(SchemaEditor
>   origSchema, SchemaEditor newSchema, SchemaWriter schemaWriter) in
>   c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Storage\Schema\SchemaEditor.cs:line
>   74 at
>   SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Schema.SchemaEditor.Register() in
>   c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Storage\Schema\SchemaEditor.cs:line
>   25 at
>   SenseNet.ContentRepository.Schema.ContentTypeInstaller.ExecuteBatch()
>   in
>   c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\Schema\ContentTypeInstaller.cs:line
>   110 at
>   SenseNet.Tools.ContentImporter.ImporterClass.InstallContentTypeDefinitionsAndAspects(String
>   ctdPath, String aspectsPath) in
>   c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Tools\Import\ImporterClass.cs:line
>   388 at SenseNet.Tools.ContentImporter.ImporterClass.Run(String
>   schemaPath, String asmPath, String fsPath, String repositoryPath,
>   Boolean validate, Boolean resetSecurity) in
>   c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Tools\Import\ImporterClass.cs:line
>   130 at SenseNet.Tools.ContentImporter.Importer.Main(String[] args) in
>   c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Tools\Import\Importer.cs:line
>   115 2017-02-01 19:46:27.5419    ---- Inner Exception: 2017-02-01
>   19:46:27.5579    InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has
>   completed; it is no longer usable. 2017-02-01 19:46:27.6070       at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Rollback() at
>   SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Data.SqlClient.Transaction.Rollback()
>   in
>   c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Storage\Data\SqlClient\Transaction.cs:line 240 at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.TransactionScope.Rollback()
>   in
>   c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Storage\TransactionScope.cs:line
>   195 at
>   SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Schema.SchemaEditor.RegisterSchema(SchemaEditor
>   origSchema, SchemaEditor newSchema, SchemaWriter schemaWriter) in
>   c:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\Storage\Schema\SchemaEditor.cs:line
>   64 2017-02-01 19:46:27.6255    ===================== 2017-02-01
>   19:46:27.6425    ======================================== 2017-02-01
>   19:46:27.6595    Import is finished with 1 errors. 2017-02-01
>   19:46:27.6775    Read log file:
>   C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\CMS\sn-community-src-6.5.4.9243\Source\SenseNet\WebSite\Tools\importlog_20170201-194504.txt

Br,
maros